# Network utilization - AccountManagement vs. DirectoryServices

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, ldap, directoryservices

I spend more than a day to find out that the Principal object is using way more bandwidth than the using the DirectoryServices. The scenario is like this. I have a group with ~3000 computer objects in it. To check if a computer is in this group I retrieved the GroupPrincipal and searched for the ComputerPrincipal.

```
        Boolean _retVal = false;
        PrincipalContext _principalContext = null;
        using (_principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainController, srv_user, srv_password)) {
            ComputerPrincipal _computer = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(_principalContext, accountName);

            GroupPrincipal _grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(_principalContext, groupName);
            if (_computer != null && _grp != null) {
                // get the members
                PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> _allGrps = _grp.GetMembers(false);
                if (_allGrps.Contains(_computer)) {
                    _retVal = true;
                }
                else {
                    _retVal = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return _retVal;
```

Actually very nice interface but this creates around 12MB traffic per request. If you're domain controller is in the LAN this is no issue. If you access the domain controller using the WAN it kills your connection/application.

After I noticed this I re-implemented the same functionality using DirectoryServices

```
Boolean _retVal = false;
DirectoryContext _ctx = null;
try {
    _ctx = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.DirectoryServer, domainController, srv_user, srv_password);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // do something useful
}
if (_ctx != null) {
    try {
        using (DomainController _dc = DomainController.GetDomainController(_ctx)) {
            using (DirectorySearcher _search = _dc.GetDirectorySearcher()) {
                String _groupToSearchFor = String.Format("CN={0},", groupName);
                _search.PropertiesToLoad.Clear();
                _search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
                _search.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectCategory=computer)(name={0}))", accountName); ;
                SearchResult _one = null;
                _one = _search.FindOne();
                if (_one != null) {
                    int _count = _one.Properties["memberOf"].Count;
                    for (int i = 0; i < _count; i++) {
                        string _m = (_one.Properties["memberOf"][i] as string);
                        if (_m.Contains(groupName)) { _retVal = true; }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // do something useful
    }
}
return _retVal;
```

This implementation will use around 12K of network traffic. Which is maybe not as nice but saves a lot of bandwith.

My questions is now if somebody has an idea what the AccountManagement object is doing that it uses so much bandwith?

THANKS!

Comment: I'm developping something with AccountManagement interface, I'd be glad to know more about this...

Comment: I am happy to save you some time :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would guess including the following lines will do a lot to save bandwidth:

```
_search.PropertiesToLoad.Clear();
_search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
_search.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectCategory=computer)(name={0}))", accountName);
```

The first two are telling the DirectorySearcher to only load a single property instead of who knows how many, of arbitrary size.

The second is passing a filter into the DirectorySearcher, which I guess is probably processed server side, further limiting the size of your result set.

Comment: In the second example I just load the required example. This version also just generates ~12k of traffic. The first version which is the cleaner and nicer version creates more traffice.

Comment: Removed part of my answer where I'd got mixed up.

Comment: Ok - But this is what I am doing in the second example which is ok on the network utilization. The issue I have is regarding the first example.

Comment: Well, no I'm not sure why the ComputerPrincipal method generates so much more bandwidth - other than it is probably dragging down EVERY property of every entity from the server to the client (generating the traffic) and filtering them there, whereas your second implementation appears to be sending search criteria to the server and the filtering happens there, returning just the relevant results to the client (resulting in much less traffic).